# How to bind Service and get data from the service in Android?

Tags: android, service

I want to bind to a Service.I want to get data from Service before on Resume function of mainActivity.Where should I call bindService() function in main activity?

Kindly help!
Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    ArrayList<City> selected_cities;
    ArrayList<City> cities;
    RecyclerView Rview;
    CitySelectedListAdapter adapter;
    final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    ICityDao dao;

    TimezoneService timezoneService ;
    boolean bound = false;

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            timezoneService = ((TimezoneService.LocalBinder ) service).getService();
            Log.d("Service connected","Service Connected ");
            bound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        bound = false;
        }
    } ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dao = new CItyDao(this);
        selected_cities = new ArrayList<City>();
        showMessage("Created");

        create_City_list();


        Intent intent  = new Intent(this,TimezoneService.class);
        bindService(intent,connection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        Log.d("created","activity created ");


    }
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        showMessage("Resumed");
        Log.d("Resume","resume ");
        selected_cities = cities.get(0).load(dao);
        if(selected_cities.size()!=0) {
            CreateListView();
        }

        for (int i =0;i< selected_cities.size();i++)
        {
            load_checkbox(selected_cities.get(i).getName());

        }


    }
}
```

Here is the service code  I want to call connectTimezonedb() written in service and get the data from this function of the service before the main activity is resumed. Please Help!

```
public class TimezoneService extends Service {

    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Onbind","onBind ");
        ConenctTimezoneDb();
        return binder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        public TimezoneService getService()
        {
            return TimezoneService.this;
        }
    };
    public void ConenctTimezoneDb()
    {
        Log.d("connect timezone","connected with time zone db");

        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/list-time-zone?&format=xml&country=US");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: bind your service in onStart() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind as soon as you can, so `onCreate` is proper place, but

> I want to get data from Service before on Resume function of mainActivity.

you simply can't ensure that. `Service` and `Activity` have own separated lifecycles, you can't be shure that `Service` even started before `onResume` in `Activity` gets called

btw. you revealed your key for API in url...

Comment: Should I call startCommand() function on on Create method to start service before on Resume()?

Comment: no, you can't do anything with that, you can't be shure that `Service` started before `onResume`. thats how framework works and all component started by `Intent`s

Comment: Can callbacks be used to ensure whether service has started or not ?

Comment: what is a "callback" in your meaning? kind-of callback is `onServiceConnected` method, will be called only when `Service` bound properly. another approach is to keep `public static boolean isRunning = false` in Service, setting it to `true` in `onCreate` and `false` in `onDestroy` - this variable will be accessible from anywhere

Comment: Basically I want to download names of cities  and their timezone values trough web and store them in db using a service. Then I want to use stored values in the db  and load them in  OnResume() method .How can I do that ?

Comment: you just can't ensure that these objects will be fetched from web, stored in db and available for GUI part (`Activity`). start `Service` as soon as you can (so `onCreate`), download and store data, then [send message](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger) to an `Activity` informing that database is fulfilled. Then you can load data in `Activity`. In most cases it won't happen before `onResume`, so just make some "loading layout" informing user that (down)loading is still in progress